# Roles / Permissions framework for c#?

Tags: c#, .net, security, permissions, roles

Does anyone know of a good framework to allow me design permission and roles against users.

Basically allowing me to automatically check a user can do a certain thing, and then disabling or enabling menu items etc

I am not really looking for asp.net security ... as i need to use it in my own service layer and clients both WEB and WPF will use it.

I was hoping for something that allows me to create new roles and groups against users and then check what type of permissions a user has or a group has

Any help really appreciated..

I am sure some kind of open source framework is available, well i was hoping not having to create my own

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Membership
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the features that ASP.NET membership/role providers (SQL Server providers for instance) give you are sufficient, I suggest you use them. You can create a web service interface for your WPF application that uses the same providers to query the user list and roles. They are in no way limited to "web forms" only.

Even if you decide not to use the built-in providers, I suggest you still access your own stuff through ASP.NET's provider system by creating custom providers. That way, anything in ASP.NET that relies on standard users/roles will "just work".